# Приложение лагает при получении текста с сайта [c++]

Tags: c++, curl

Через Curl получаю текст с сервера. Но когда приложение переходит в окно где выводится этот текст, оно начинает очень сильно лагать
Пробовал использовать callonce, и ставить статик, но это не помогло

Код:

```
    static std::string ret = "\0";
    const  std::string req_buf1;

    static char er_buf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    // static string days;
    static std::string url_ = "https://site.ru/api/get_user_game_subscribe/" +
        string(login) +
        "/" +
        password +
        "/" +
        GetHWID() +
        "/" +
        "11";
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode result;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, er_buf);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url_);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "lxader");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &req_buf1);
        result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (result == CURLE_OK) {
            ret = req_buf1;
        }

    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);


        ImGui::Text(req_buf1.c_str());
```

Гиф лагов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вынесите в отдельный поток

Comment: @SKIP Это не помогло. Либо я просто не умею адекватно выносить в отдельный поток

Comment: я не телепат, код покажите

Comment: тогда надо смотреть весь код. Скорее всего там глобальный лок. Или переходить в асинхронный режим.

Comment: @SKIP https://imgur.com/a/5zba9uk Сделал по гайду в интернете
Мне сказали что у меня идёт постоянное подключение к серверу. И он обновляет текст каждый кадр. Но как сделать чтобы оно не шло постоянно, я так и не допёр

Comment: все логично - у Вас там join - а оно блокирует до победного конца. Попробуйте заменить на deattach().

Comment: @KoVadim `detach()`*

Comment: @KoVadim поставил detach() но теперь текст с сервера не выводится вообще

Comment: да, сложно переключаться с кастомного  своего stl на официальный...

Comment: @Jakee - конечно не будет отображаться - сохраните эти данные куда то во внешнюю переменную и потом уже отрисовывайте

Comment: @KoVadim заметил ещё одну вещь, теперь приложение вылетает постоянно 
Но если убрать детач то работает

а ещё как сохранить во внешнюю переменную? Я в C++ не так давно, многого не знаю, и очень сильно могу тупить

Comment: я ж надеюсь у вас этот код находитсся не в потоке отрисовки? а то он реально выполняется каждый кадр, тормозит отрисовку (которая лагает каждый раз)

Comment: вообще работа с сетью делается на отдельном уровне и связывается с гуи через  любой асинхронный интерфейс (сигналы/слоты из кьют, нотифаи и сообщения из винды и т.д.) если делать это синхронно, даже в обработчиках кнопок, то будет лагать и виснуть

Comment: @goldstar_labs вообще да в отрисовке, но я тупенький, не могу допереть как сделать так чтобы текст вывелся в отрисовке, но код получения текста не был в нём)

Comment: Вообще у меня есть библиотека с помощью которой я бы вывел текст адекватно
Но с ней у меня не может скомпилироваться приложение, выдавая ошибку
https://sun1-17.userapi.com/vEf02CaHmcA4fz8UwHv6yvTvSXbTyEkQi0ceUA/AD_tI9dOoag.jpg